# Postfix/Postscreen Rejecting e-mails from Gmail

Tags: postfix, gmail, blacklist

I have a Postfix mail server installed on an Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS server running on an [Antsle Nano](https://go.antsle.com/antsle-nano/) device. Postfix was installed as a part of the [iRedMail](https://www.iredmail.org/) package, which preinstalls a host of additional mail utilities such as Amavisd, Dovecot, and Fail2Ban to help Linux n00bs like myself in having a functional, reliable, and relatively secure mail server quickly. When I initially got everything set up, it all seemed to be working pretty much flawlessly.

However, today I tried to send an e-mail message to my domain's Postfix server from a Gmail account that never arrived in my Inbox. After looking at the logs, it seems that the IP address of the Gmail mail server that tried to deliver the message has gotten listed on `dbl.spamhaus.org`, so the server rejected it:

```
Jul 30 18:57:59 smtp postfix/postscreen[7559]: CONNECT from [209.85.216.48]:36792 to [XX.XX.XX.XX]:25
Jul 30 18:57:59 smtp postfix/dnsblog[7561]: addr 209.85.216.48 listed by domain zen.spamhaus.org as 127.255.255.254
Jul 30 18:58:05 smtp postfix/postscreen[7559]: PASS NEW [209.85.216.48]:36792
Jul 30 18:58:05 smtp postfix/smtpd[7563]: connect from mail-pj1-f48.google.com[209.85.216.48]
Jul 30 18:58:06 smtp postfix/smtpd[7563]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-pj1-f48.google.com[209.85.216.48]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256
Jul 30 18:58:06 smtp postfix/smtpd[7563]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-pj1-f48.google.com[209.85.216.48]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Sender address [myuser@gmail.com] blocked using dbl.spamhaus.org; from=<myuser@gmail.com> to=<recipient@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-pj1-f48.google.com>
Jul 30 18:58:39 smtp postfix/smtpd[7563]: disconnect from mail-pj1-f48.google.com[209.85.216.48] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 bdat=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8
```

I understand that legitimate mail servers will often get temporarily listed by DNSBL/RBL services because spammers use them to peddle their wares, but I don't particularly want to face this issue when a message is sent from what should be a totally legitimate source.

When I went to research the problem, I came across a thread on HowToForge titled **[Postfix whitelist how to add gmail to whitelist](https://forum.howtoforge.com/threads/postfix-whitelist-how-to-add-gmail-to-whitelist.82267/)**. The answer that was suggested was to use Postscreen instead of explicit DNSBL filtering for spam as Postscreen is basically supposedly "more forgiving" about such things.

Based on the iRedMail documentation for [enabling Postscreen](https://docs.iredmail.org/enable.postscreen.html), cross-referenced with the documentation on [enabling DNSBL services](https://docs.iredmail.org/enable.dnsbl.html), I took a look at my `/etc/postfix/master.cf` to make sure that I didn't have any over-zealous spam filtering rules in place. However, what I found *seems* to indicate that I'm already "just" using Postscreen:

What iRedMail says should be in place if Postfix is enabled:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

My `master.cf`

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
```

The information on enabling DNSBL says that there should be a block similar to this in the `master.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    ...
    reject_unauth_destination
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]
    reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2
```

But I have no such block. It also says that, if I'm running Postscreen, there should be a block like this:

```
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
    zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*3
    b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2*2
```

But, again, my `master.cf` does not contain any such block. Of course, now I'm even *more* confused because, if it isn't *supposed* to be using DNSBL filtering, why did the Gmail message get rejected?

As stated above, I'm pretty much a "novice" when it comes to the *nix environment, so I'm not sure exactly where to look next. I *could* just try to whitelist my own Gmail address, but I'd much rather find a solution that isn't quite so specific.

Am I headed in the right troubleshooting direction, or am I overlooking something (*certainly not out of the question*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run: "grep -ris spamhaus /etc"

you probably have "reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org" (without "=127..." part) somewhere in your config, so the mail gets rejected when dns resolves to 127.255.255.254, which in it's turn indicates you are using public resolver on your mail server

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I found it. (*I **really** need to learn how to use `grep`*). I also found that the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` block *does*, in fact, exist, so I apparently completley overlooked it before. So, now, if I understand correctly, all I should need to do is add `gmail.com` to the `rbl_override` to prevent messages from Gmail from being blocked simply because the server IP is in the Spamhaus DNSBL, but other "rules" should still be able to catch spam based on subject, body, etc., right?

Comment: no! if you want to use spamhaus you should not use public dns resolvers on your mailserver, otherwise spamhaus will still sometimes answer with 127.255.255.25X codes. as a workaround you can add the 127-part to "reject_rbl_client" like this: "reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]" instead of just "reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org". it will ignore irrelevant codes. it can let some spam in though but will avoid false positives.

Comment: in fact "workaround" is a poor word choice by me. you really should explicitly tell postfix what codes to expect for blacklisted ips in case there is possibility of other non-blacklist related codes, which is the case with spamhaus.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. As I said, I'm a total *nix n00b, so I'm still trying to figure out the best way to configure a lot of these things.